# Are there any unique Id for every user connects to my web server?

Tags: asp.net

I need a unique ID for every user connects to my Web server(web site). 
How can I earn it?

Comment: Post the Code which you have tried up to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GUid and store it in session:

> string id =
>   System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
>   Session["id"] = id;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SessionID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property. It is unique for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you could generate your own unique ids, and store them in cookies.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want a Session ID or a User Id.

If you want the Id to be retained for a given User, then you need to create a permanent cookie for that user. I'd suggest using the Application_BeginRequest method in Global.asax, check the Request cookies - if they have the cookie you created then extract the Id - otherwise create a new one using the Guid class:

```
 if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] == null)
 {
      HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
      newCookie .Values["Id"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
 }
```